# Element 'UpdatePanel' is not a known element

Tags: asp.net

I have one master page in project. I added scripmanager in that page. In one aspx page I added only update panel control because script manager is in master page.I open both file of master page and save. Still I am getting an error Element 'UpdatePanel' is not a known element.

Comment: Please provide relevant mark-up & code to help us diagnose your problem.

Comment: What version of .net are you using?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2005.

Comment: Are you using .Net 1.0/2.0/3.5/4.0 ?

Comment: Dot.net framework 2.0.And ajaxcontroltoolkit 1.0.

Comment: I have 2 project.I am using vs 2005.There is already ajax extention in toolbar and ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll in bin folder.person who was previous already add this.In one project when I am fetching control of ajax from toolbar,appropriate assembly comes in aspx page.But this is not case in second project.I choosed that dll by adding reference.still there is no progress.I create new tab called ajaxtoolkit and choosed that dll.All ajax control appeared.That dll is AjaxcontrolToolkit.dll version 1.0

Comment: Have you tried adding the script manager to the page just to see if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 7):

Found this [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1646008.aspx/1)

Basically quit VS2010, delete the content of your 'Reflected Schema Cache', which should be in something like this:

```
C:\Users\[Your Username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ReflectedSchemas
```

Restart VS and you should have fixed it.

Comment: Had same problem & tried this. Intellisense error disappeared at first but then came straight back.

Comment: You can go right to AppData with the following location `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ReflectedSchemas`

Comment: Tried this and no luck :(!

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issue and I figured that if we have UpdatePanel under "div" or "span" or even "asp:Content" the VS intellisense doesn't complain. Its strange though.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same problem and also tried to drag and drop from the toolbox to no avail. I finally was able to solve it by adding the targetFramework="4.0" attribute to my compilation tag in my web.config file.

Comment: Had same problem & tried this, but it didn't make any difference for me.

Answer (score 2):

Put the following code in your web config. Just change assembly according to your Ajaxtoolkit

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to resolve the **'Element 'UpdatePanel' is not a known element'** error if you're using **VS2008** or targetting earlier frameworks.

You need to explicitly include the following controls/namespaces in your web.config's *pages* section, contained within *system.web*.

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
```

I was getting this error in VS 2015 due to reference to 3.5 in System.Web.Extensions page directive. Make sure it's 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when I changed from an older .Net to a later .Net 4 framework. Also changed to XHTML5.
In XHTML5 the  is not allowed which was used, which affected parsing, which caused the error/warning.
Once I replaced  with  then it stopped the warnings.

Comment: replaced what with what?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, here is how I solved it:

With your `ScriptManager`, add it before your `UpdatePanel`, but close it's tag instead of putting the `UpdatePanel` and `ContentTemplate` inside of it.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="nonflashymanager" runat="server"/>
<asp:UpdatePanel id="nonflashyform" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    </ContentTemplate>
</UpdatePanel>
```